# How to pause and resume a while loop in Python?

Tags: python, loops

I want to have a loop running that will print "Hello" and when I press "K" it stops printing but it doesn't end the program, then when I press "K" again it starts printing again.

I tried this(using the *keyboard* module):

```
import keyboard

running = True

while running == True:
    print("hello")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("k"):
        if running == True:
            running = False
        else:
            running = True
```

but when I press the button it just ends the program and that's not what I'm trying to do. I understand why it ends but I don't know how to make it not end. How can I do that?

Comment: You'll need a second nested while, one for the general program, and one for the `print("hello")`.

Comment: when you want terminate completely

Comment: You need different conditions to display and stop the loop, look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import keyboard

running = True
display = True
block = False

while running:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("k"):
        if block == False:
            display = not display
            block = True
    else:
        block = False
    if display:
        print("hello")
    else:
        print("not")
```

Comment: Thank you. I just changed:
`else:
     print("not")`
to:
`else:
     pass`
and it's working as intended. Thank you again.

Comment: hahah, I did that for my usage and forget about that :D

Comment: Please note that, if you add print("stop/start") in Adrian Melon's program, you can see his program prints several time "hello" after 'k' is pressed until the buffer will be empty.You must empty the buffer, you can examine my answer.

Comment: @rouhollahghasempour are you sure? If I understand correctly, you will see this "several time "hello"" until you stop pushing 'k' button, method only check if key is pressed at the moment of its call. Don't you put `print("stop/start")` in a wrong place?

Comment: @adrianmelon yes I ran my program and your program and you can check both of them. I put print("stop/start") in the line that is executed after the 'k' is pressed. The problem rises as keyboard.is_pressed does not empty the buffer. As, the keys have two bytes, we need to read two bytes by doit = msvcrt.getch().decode('utf-8').

Comment: I don't understand problem. Could you give example of console output, which shows problem with buffer?

Comment: @adrianmelon I put the output of both codes. please check it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a handler for the keypress, which sets an event that the main thread can then test for periodically, and wait if required.

(Note that there are two types of events here, the keypress event and the setting of the `running`, so these should not be confused.)

```
from threading import Event
from time import sleep
import keyboard

hotkey = 'k'

running = Event()
running.set()  # at the start, it is running

def handle_key_event(event):
    if event.event_type == 'down':
        # toggle value of 'running'
        if running.is_set():
            running.clear()
        else:
            running.set()

# make it so that handle_key_event is called when k is pressed; this will 
# be in a separate thread from the main execution
keyboard.hook_key(hotkey, handle_key_event)

while True:
    if not running.is_set():
        running.wait()  # wait until running is set
    sleep(0.1)        
    print('hello')
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that:

```py
import keyboard

running = True
stop = False

while !stop:

    if keyboard.is_pressed("k"):
        running = !running          # Stops "hello" while
    if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
        stop = !stop                # Stops general while

    if running:

        print("hello")
```

Comment: It stops printing but I can't get it to resume.

Comment: @MentalCombination I edit the answer, please review it and give a feedback.

Comment: @TheRnk Pressing "k" doesn't do anything. Regardless, another user solved it. Thank you still.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import keyboard
from time import sleep

running = True

while running:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("k"):
        sleep(1)
    elif keyboard.is_presed('Esc'):
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("hello")
```

I didnt test it, so please give me feedback

Comment: It stops printing while I'm holding down "k", when I let go it waits 1 second and it starts printing again. What I'm trying to do is have the button "k" as a switch.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way is flushing the buffer, because the previous solutions may print more. This works for windows, for Linux, you should refer to [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

```
import time
import subprocess
import sys
import msvcrt

printing = True
while (1):
    # Try to flush the buffer
    while not msvcrt.kbhit() and printing:
        print("hello")

    doit = msvcrt.getch().decode('utf-8')
    if doit=="k":
        printing = not printing
        print("stop/start")
    if doit == 'q':
        break
```

This is the output of this code:
[image]
Please note that, if you add print("stop/start") in Adrian Melon's program, you can see his program prints several time "hello" after 'k' is pressed until the buffer will be empty.

```
    import keyboard

    running = True
    display = True
    block = False

    while running:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("k"):
            print("stop/start")
            if block == False:
                display = not display
                block = True
        else:
            block = False
        if display:
            print("hello")
        else:
            pass
```

This is the output of @Adrian-Melon program:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about the problem you mean, but cloudn't you write line `print("stop/start")` after my `display = not display` to improve comparability of our codes? In your code this line is after analogous `printing = not printing`.

Comment: print("stop/start") is executed after 'k' is pressed (a key is pressed and that key is 'k'). the 'block' variable is your own that is not related to 'k' is pressed. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user. We should stop this discussion. Good luck.

Comment: `block` is necessary to use `k` button as toggle switch, without it `k` would toggle print condition every loop pass. In my code pressing `k` is not sufficient condition to toggle `display` variable, opposite to your solution. Your `stop/start` should be after toggle condition to make sense. I think you misunderstood my code, but I agree that it is enough discussion about that. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

```
import keyboard

running = True
display = True
block = False

while running:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("space"):
        if block == False:
            display = not display
            block = True
    else:
        block = False
    if display:
        print("hello")
    else:
        input("Press Enter to continue...")
        if block == False:
            display = not display
            block = True
```

You can use this to stop and start again.

Comment: I am sure it would help the community if you explained to us why and how you code would solve the OP's problem

Comment: When I ran the code given by IzZy, it didn't stop printing, it just continued to print "not", so I made this code smoother in my own project. My code works like this: We press the "Space" key to stop the printing loop, then if we want to continue our code again, we press the "Enter" key and our printing loop continues. This code worked for me. @SimasJoneliunas